# Is it possible to launch Firefox with a set of add-ons using command line?

Tags: command-line, firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm looking for a way to launch Firefox with a set of specified add-ons using command line.

E.g.

```
$ firefox --plugin-list=/home/user/addons/quickjava-2.0.4-fx.xpi,\
            /home/user/addons/adblock.xpi,\
            /home/user/addons/flashblock.xpi
```

etc.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to specify specific add-ons and extensions, but depending on your requirements there might be another solution.

Add-ons and extensions are tied to a profile. You can have multiple profiles and you *can* select a profile when starting Firefox.

1. Start the profile manager with `firefox -ProfileManager`
2. Create a new profile and add the add-ons you want
3. Start Firefox using the newly created profile with `firefox -P"<ProfileName>"`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link for more information on firefox command line usage
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points in your answer and use the link as reference. Thanks.